# Webpack hot reload doesn't stop html5 audio

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, html5-audio

In a Vue app I play background music, using the audio tag :

```
<audio id="music" autoplay loop>
  <source
    :src="musicfilename"
    type="audio/mp3"
  />
</audio>
```

This works fine, but when the app is restarted during development, by Webpack 'hot reload', the music that was playing isn't stopped, so it keeps playing multiple music instances at the same time!

When I check with `document.getElementsByTagName` there is really only 1 instance of `AUDIO`, so I can't find a way to stop the previous audio instances from playing.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this `<audio>` contained into component?

Comment: Actually I'm using Howler.js in mounted, instead of audio tag now. But the problem remains.

Comment: can you destroy the `Howler` instance when the module is being replaced?

Comment: Also try to destroy it in `destroyed` hook.

Comment: Thanks, I put Howler.unload() in mounted, which seems to fix it !

Answer (score 0):

You should track when your module is being hot replaced, and when it is just stop the audio player.

```html
<audio id="music" ref="player" autoplay loop>
  <source
    :src="musicfilename"
    type="audio/mp3"
  />
</audio>
```

```js
export default {
  ...
  mounted() {
    if (module.hot) {
      module.hot.dispose(this.hmrHandler);
    }
  },
  destroyed() {
    if (module.hot) {
      module.hot.removeDisposeHandler(this.hmrHandler)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hmrHandler() {
      const { player } = this.$refs
      player.pause()
      // Lines below can also help
      // player.currentTime = 0
      // player.src = ''
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

**Update**:
`Howler.unload()` placed in the `mounted` hook solved the problem.

[Webpack HMR API](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement).

Look at [`dispose`](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/#dispose-or-adddisposehandler) and [`removeDisposeHandler`](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/#removedisposehandler).